# Your Mileage May Vary

Tags: expressions, speech, transatlantic-differences

In the United States we have a saying, "your mileage may vary", which means "your experience may be different".  In English-speaking countries that don't use Imperial miles, is there an equivalent expression?

Comment: Please share your research or search results.

Comment: Your mileage may vary imperially?  Your km/l rate may vary?

Comment: @Rob - but that's not an equivalent expression, as no one says that to indicate that experiences concerning product life, for example, may vary from product to product and person to person, which how 'Your mileage may vary' can be used in English, but not in Dutch, for example.

Comment: The phrase that comes to mind first is 'In het verleden behaalde resultaten bieden geen geen garantie voor de toekomst.', which means 'past results are no guarantee for future results'. This is mostly used in relation to finance, but can be used as a colloquialism in situations where an outcome may or may not be as desirable as an earlier outcome.

Comment: To make a pedant's point, we don't use Imperial measurements in the United States, we use U.S. customary units, although both Imperial units and US. customary units are based on English customary units. For units of length/distance, or otherwise standardized prior to American independence, there is no difference; however, an Imperial gallon is much bigger than a U.S. gallon, and an Imperial ton would be known as a long ton stateside.

Comment: Interesting, @choster, I didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question (thought it said 'non-English-speaking countries').

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8175/usage-of-ymmv-can-i-use-it-in-day-to-day-conversation

Comment: Here is a discussion on the subject: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YourMileageMayVary

Comment: There is an idiom of sorts used by the financial industry (and familiar to the general public from the fast talk at the end of commercials) along the lines of "past performance is no indication of future behavior", but the exact wording isn't coming to me so I'll let someone else look it up.

Comment: https://money-markets-blog.amazon.com/post/Tx2ZCE130STORLK/Past-Performance-is-Not-Necessarily-Indicative-of-Future-Results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some countries, the industry practice is to express fuel economy in terms of the amount of fuel consumed to travel 100km. Thus, *kilometerage* doesn't make any more sense than *mileage* does. *Top Gear* Netherlands expresses fuel economy as *verbruik* (*consumption*), e.g. *Verbruik stad: 19.0 l/100km*.

But you wouldn't say *your consumption may vary* either, because *your mileage may vary* has become a fixed expression thanks to its popularity in digital culture, and there's nothing wrong with using it even if you have no idea how long a *mile* is (or [which *mile*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mile) you're referring to).

As established in another question, *[Mileage as unit-agnostic term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141719)*, **the term *mileage* does not require that the measurement be done using miles**. The *mile* is a longstanding unit, going back to antiquity, and as a concept of distance is thus embedded deep in the language. The OED attests to *mileage* in the sense of fuel consumption from 1926:

> The tendency… is to produce… engines of increased compression ratio, in order mainly to diminish the petrol consumption and increase mileage per gallon consumed.

from the journal *Science* 10 Sept. 237/1. But the metaphorical sense of *mileage*—the extent of benefit or advantage one can obtain from something— is actually even older, from at least 1860:

> It has been a heavy mileage of neglect for which we have already paid dearly.

(W. H. Russell, *My Diary in India* I.x.155)

So an English-speaker can say *mileage* regardless of whether your miles are nautical miles, kilometers, stade, li, or [smoots](http://aether.lbl.gov/www/personnel/smoot/smoot-measure.html). *Top Gear* India gives *mileage* estimates in kpl (kilometers per litre).

---

The specific phrasing *Your Mileage May Vary* originates in U.S. federal regulation. The [Energy Policy and Conservation Act of 1975](https://www.congress.gov/bill/94th-congress/senate-bill/622) mandated that the U.S. Environmental Protection Agency (EPA) administer a [fuel economy testing system](http://www3.epa.gov/fueleconomy/regulations.htm) for passenger cars and light trucks. Starting in 1978, a placard like this one was attached to all new cars sold in the United States:

[image: Actual mileage will vary]

(the design has been subsequently revised several times)

The disclaimer *actual mileage will vary* was variously rendered in advertising; *EPA estimate; your actual mileage may vary* and variants were ritualistically intoned in many a television and radio ad. The *your mileage may vary* variant happened to be the one that became popularized in digital culture, and with the rise of the retail Internet, *YMMV* became ubiquitous.

---

Although I'm sure there are generalized sayings with the lesson to *manage your expectations*, now my brain seems to be fixated on regulatory and liability-limiting language. *YMMV* is the only one that has migrated to online culture, however, so if anything, these alternatives are even more specific to the US and would only be recognizable as set expressions to Americans:

- Results may vary
- Kids, don't try this at home
- Past performance is no guarantee of future results
- Price and participation may vary
- No other warranty express or implied
- Contents may settle during shipment
- Other restrictions may apply

Essentially, any warning message that reality may not live up to the advertised ideal could apply, but the wording of the message would be localized.

Comment: I can't read all those without thinking: _Batteries not included_.

Comment: Interesting and certainly worthy of upvoting.

Answer (score 4):

In Canada at least, where use of the kilometre is normal "Your mileage may vary" is well understood in its internet sense. In fact the word 'mileage' is sometimes used even when expressing gas consumption in litres per kilometre. (Although 'fuel economy' or 'gas consumption' is the norm. 'Kilometrage' is used almost never.

- http://www.wheels.ca/top-ten/top-7-fuel-efficient-cars-save-money-pump/

Comment: +1 for your unqualified mention of "consumption," although I think "gas"  can be omitted, just as it [as well as "per gallon"] is omitted in the OP's "[gas] **mileage** [per gallon]": "[Your actual consumption may vary](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22your+gas+consumption+may%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22your+actual+consumption+may+vary%22)."

Answer (score 1):

From [oxforddictionaries...](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/circumstances-alter-cases)

> **circumstances alter cases** (proverb)
>    *One’s opinion or treatment of someone or something may vary according to the prevailing circumstances.*

That's a slightly more restrictive definition than I would expect, since it can just as well apply to one's *experience* being different (as opposed to *opinions* or *treatment* of something).

Comment: Great.  Another driveby downvote, a curse upon this site.  Why doesn't this capture "your experience may be different"?  Not catchy enough?  Not enough of a commercial parody?  Alas, we can't tell.  This behavior leaves bad answers uncorrected, and it leaves good answers with the impression that they're bad answers.

Comment: @deadrat: I'm a bit baffled by this one. But I assume I must be somehow missing the point of the question *as perceived by others here*, given that as of now 7 people have been moved to upvote the Q (i.e. - they must think there's *something* that would qualify as a "correct" answer). Yet only 3 *answer* upvotes have been doled out (one each to three *different* answers, none of which would satisfy *me*). But I've been here long enough that I don't get irritated any more (just *baffled, intrigued!* :)

Comment: I agree with deadrat that the downvote here was absurd.

Comment: @Sven: I guess that's your upvote that saves me further public shaming then, ty! :) But [to some extent](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310082/your-mileage-may-vary/310088?noredirect=1#comment700060_310092) the question is a bit meaningless. The generation after mine in the UK don't "use" pounds (to them it's all kilograms), but they'd still demand their ***pound of flesh*** if the context arose. (Me, I'm still prepared to ask someone if they've got their ***seven-league boots,*** by way of warning them it's a long way to walk to wherever they've just asked directions for! :)

Comment: Conversely in the land of the almighty dollar, I have no difficulty understanding (and even using) "in for a penny, in for a pound" and "penny wise, pound foolish," to cite a couple of pounds of another sort that happen to be alien to the local monetary system. But others' kilometrage will vary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are obviously a more highly evolved person than me.  I'm not sure why DBDVing irritates me so much.  Part of it is the rudeness; part is the missed opportunity for an improved answer.  (Perhaps you are missing the point, but we don't know.)  Part is the possibility of misleading of learners who might think a correct answer is wrong.  And a comment is so easy.  Even "I can't use this but I don't know why" would be acceptable.  And part is that I'm just irritable.

Comment: @deadrat: Spend a few more years on ELU, *live* a few more decades, then ask yourself whether you want to spend what time remains to you on this earth competing in *Grumpy Ole Git of the Year* contests. With luck, you'll make the right choice, and find your irritability will at least *reduce* a bit. (But if my experience is anything to go by, you'll never shake it completely! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Alas, I've been banned from the *Grumpy Ole Git of the Year* contest.  "Fercryanoutloud," they said.  "Give someone else a chance, won't you?"  When someone annoys me, I've found it helps to mentally go to my "happy place," a beautiful glade on a sunny day, with a gentle breeze blowing, birds chirping, and a brook babbling.  And when I look down I can see the face of the person annoying me as I hold his head under the water of the brook.

Comment: @deadrat: Haven't tried that approach. Can you update your profile to include a pic? I'm not very imaginative, so that would be a great help to me if/when I fall off my pinnacle of serenity! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You want a picture of me holding somebody's head under water?  I believe that in court, they call that an admission against interest.

Answer (score 1):

***[Your mileage may vary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary):***

> - In the United States, the Environmental Protection Agency requires a set of standard emissions tests on all new vehicles which simulate city and highway driving. Part of the test measures estimated city and highway gas mileage estimates. Since no test can exactly simulate all driving habits and conditions, actual gas mileage of each vehicle will vary. As a result, when these estimated mileage claims from automobile manufacturers appear in advertisements, they are almost always accompanied with the standard disclaimer "your mileage may vary."

An alternative is ***it may work differently for you***.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, because in encompasses both fuel economy metrics (be they miles/gallon or furlongs/hogshead) and the colloquialism often abbreviated in the techronym YMMV. +1, with a dollop of ethanol.

Comment: So a location that does not use miles but let's say kilometers, will still state "your mileage may vary"?  (I interpreted the OP's question to be exactly that question - what would a non-miles-measuring country use in place of that statement?)

Comment: @Kristina: *What did you say? Sorry - I was **miles** away.* If that didn't hit the spot, I guess I'll have to concede that *a miss is as good as a **mile*** :)

Answer (score 1):

Cooking instructions on pre-packaged food in the UK often contains the warning:

> Appliances may vary. Ensure product is cooked though before serving.

The phrase

> Appliances may vary

is not vey common in speech, but is sometimes used and has roughly the same meaning.

Although we use miles, YMMV is not a common phrase.